# Comparing two proofs of Jordan Decomposition

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, geometry, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

$\newcommand{\g}{\mathfrak{g}}$
$\newcommand{\GL}{\operatorname{GL}}$

A proof of the standard Jordan decomposition theorems for algebraic groups (and their Lie algebras) can be found in Borel, I.4.4. I recall the key points of the proof for groups below.

We begin by intrinsically characterizing semisimplicity/unipotence of elements of $G(k)$ in terms of their locally finite action on the coordinate ring. Then one checks that the usual decomposition in $\operatorname{GL}_n$ induces this decomposition of operators on the coordinate ring. For general $G$, choose a closed embedding $G \hookrightarrow \GL_n$ corresponding to ideal $I$. Then one can characterize $G$ and $\g$ inside the larger group/algebra as the elements whose action on the coordinate ring preserves $J$. Since on each finite-dimensional stable subspace of the coordinate ring, $g_s$ and $g_u$ are given by polynomials in $g$, they each preserve $J$, so $g_s$ and $g_u$ are elements of $\GL_n(k)$ which preserve $J$, hence are in $G(k)$.

The proof above is almost the same as the one in Brian Conrad's very careful notes [here](http://virtualmath1.stanford.edu/%7Econrad/252Page/handouts/alggroups.pdf), section 13 and appendix B. However, one extra step adds extra complexity. When showing that the semisimple and nilpotent parts of $i(X)$ lie in $G(k)$, Theorem 14.1.1 (that any subgroup can be made the normalizer of a line) is cited to reduce the problem from $G \hookrightarrow \GL_n$ to $\GL_m \hookrightarrow \GL_n$. Then he checks functoriality of the Jordan decomposition for such embeddings, using basically the same reasoning as above, to conclude the result.

**Question**: As far as I can tell, Borel's argument is fully complete (though not stated scheme-theoretically). Is Conrad's extra reduction necessary? Why? I fear Borel's proof is obfuscating some scheme-theoretic detail or logical circularity in the definitions.